# In carrierwave, using simple_fields_for, iterating on a symbol (:pictures), how do I find the symbol for the image URLs?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, symbols, simple-form

I have a `_form` which renders another form with `simple_fields_for`. Everything works fine except I can't figure out the symbol that holds the different URLs, I particularly want the thumb URL.

For example, `picture.image_uploader_url` — but I don't have the actual object, just the :pictures symbol which is being iterated on. So far `:image_uploader_url.to_s` doesn't give anything useful and I realized this is because that will always just give the symbol name.

Super form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@project) do |f| %>
[...]
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :pictures do |builder| %>
            <%= render "pictures/form", f: builder %>
[...]
```

Sub form (pictures/_form):

```
<% unless [:image_uploader_url].nil? or [:image_uploader_url].empty? %>
    <%=  image_tag(:thumb_url.to_s) %>
<% end %>
<%= f.input :name %>
<%= f.input :description %>
<%= f.input :image_uploader, as: :file %>
<%= f.hidden_field :image_uploader_cache %>
```

How do I know in general what symbols I will have access to and how do I use them? maybe I dont have them?

EDIT: I don't have 'picture' to work with, only ':pictures' which I'm struggling to find what all I can get from this (i.e. picture has an image_uploader which I can get image_uploader_url(:thumb) but I can't do this with symbols, nor do I know how to get the picture that is the current iteration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could figure out there is no way to get to the individual pictures that are related to the :pictures symbol. I ended up just scrapping the symbol and passing local variables (I was trying to avoid having the controller from making more information directly available).

I still don't have a satisfactory answer but this is the best I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

To get the thumb url for `picture`, just do this: `picture.thumb.url`. To get the original url, `picture.url` would do fine.

Comment: I got that part :) My problem is I don't have picture to work with, only :pictures, which is being iterated on, is there a way i can get the current picture in the iteration? or do I need to iterate on some_object_foo.pictures  ? Thanks for the help !

Comment: Could you provide the code where you are doing the iteration?

Comment: Absolutely! I updated the code, is that what you were looking for? Thanks again for the help!!

Comment: Could you access a picture, say, using `@project.pictures.first.url` ?

Comment: Yes but I can't get that from :pictures if I don't have @project somewhere else.

Comment: Do you want to display or upload the picture? But either way, I think you can access @project by making it available in the controller in the first place.

Comment: It's for new / edit on photos, so it sounds like the answer is to not use the symbol and just use the collection of objects?